# Morris.js charts in Bootstrap tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

i have a Problem with Charts in Tabs, not work.

A link to http://jsfiddle.net/ bchkq2L3/1/

Maybe someone has an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: I can see the charts on my computer.

Comment: both charts? one charts per tab

Comment: I see both charts on my computer one chart per tab.